# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppMeasurement is not initialized" calling FirebaseAnalytics after Firebase initialized successfully

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

After following all the guided steps about how setup Firebase 5.4.4 on iOS and Android with Unity Plugin it still doesn't work on Android. Firebase console doesn't receive any callback or event of the app but the app seems to be configured properly. The project is developed with Unity 2018.3.0f2.

The project was using Firebase plugin version 5.4.3 and I've updated to 5.4.4 with the same results. Also I've tried to delete and reinstall the Firebase plugin again (with a clean installation) without any success.

Everything seems to be connected properly and inside Firebase console Android project looks completely configured (it has been working on iOS without problem). Also I've tried with quick start app provided here (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity) showing the same exception and without receiving any event on the Firebase console.

Seeing the logcat of the app on device, it shows that Firebase is initialized properly:

> firebase: Firebase App initializing app xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx (default 1).
>   
> Unity   : Firebase App initializing app xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx (default 1).
>   
> firebase: Firebase Analytics API Initializing
>   
> Unity   : Firebase Analytics API Initializing
>   
> firebase: analytics API Initialized
>   
> Unity   : analytics API Initialized

But just after trying to send a metric using FirebaseAnalytics, the log shows the next exception:

> E FA      : Task exception on worker 
> thread: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppMeasurement is not initialized: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbw.zzcl(Unknown Source:289)

And the build.gradle file:

```js
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
  jcenter()
        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'arcore_client', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ARExtensions', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.cardview-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-api-16.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.0.5', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-16.0.6', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-unity-5.4.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-5.4.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-16.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-core-16.0.6', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-17.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-17.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.13.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-applinks', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-common', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-core', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-login', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-marketing', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-messenger', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-places', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-share', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'play-services-basement-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityAds', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'unityandroidpermissions', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityARCore', ext:'aar')
    implementation project(':Firebase')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId 'xxxxx'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 2
        versionName '0.0.2'

  multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'build_info.txt', 'google-services-desktop.json'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('xxxxxxxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
            keyAlias 'xxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }

}
```

I've configured Firebase in other Unity projects but right now I don't know where it is the source of the problem.

Comment: Is there any code snippets you could show?

Comment: I've added the build.gradle file in the description. About code snippets, Firebase is initialized properly and automatically when the Unity app starts, so I just call:

FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("metricId");

To log any metric.

Comment: Ok, this gradle file and configuration used with Unity Cloud Build to create an Android apk is working... should be something related maybe with Gradle in my local computer.

Comment: Bad news: it worked with the first build we've done with Unity Cloud Build but not with the nexts... why? No idea (same logs without failures compiling the apks).